# before insert trigger for insert duplicate rows into another table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table called `tblspmaster` in which sp column i have unique index so there will be no duplicates will be inserted, but i want to insert duplicate rows into `tblspduplicate` . so i decided to write trigger for this .  IN master table which is `tblspmaster` records will be inserted using Load File of `mysql`

```
create trigger tblspmaster_noduplicate
before insert on tblspmaster
for each row
begin
  if ( select count(sp) from tblspmaster where sp=new.sp > 0 )then
    insert into tblspduplicate (sp,FileImported,AMZFileName)   values (NEW.sp,NEW.FileImported,NEW.AMZFileName)
  END
END
```

I have list of questions

1. Is this right approach to stop duplicates and insert into another
   table ?
2. My trigger is not executing as its showing some syntax errors

ERROR response is `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END END' at line 7`

*************************EDITED***************************

here is table definition for master and duplicate table and trigger and load data file MySQL statements

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblspmaster` (
  `CSN` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SP` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `FileImportedDate` date NOT NULL,
  `AMZFileName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `CasperBatch` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `BatchProcessedDate` date NOT NULL,
  `ExpiryDate` date NOT NULL,
  `Region` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `FCCity` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `VendorID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LocationID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CSN`),
  UNIQUE KEY `SP` (`SP`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10000000000 ;




   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblspduplicate` (
      `SP` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `FileImportedDate` date NOT NULL,
      `AMZFileName` varchar(50) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

use casper;
DELIMITER $$
create trigger tblspmaster_noduplicate
before insert on tblspmaster
for each row
begin
  if ( select count(sp) from tblspmaster where sp=new.sp > 0 ) then
    insert into tblspduplicate (sp,FileImportedDate,AMZFileName)   values (NEW.sp,NEW.FileImportedDate,NEW.AMZFileName);
  END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;






LOAD DATA local INFILE 'E://31october//SP//sp_files_sample1//400k sp00 6-19 E.csv'
INTO TABLE  tblspmaster
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(sp);
```

Here is one twist in story that i am executing this MySql command from a c# console application but i dont think it will affect our db related structure or program in any way.
I also need to remove `IGNORE 1 LINES` statement as there will be no header row.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as you trigger concerned there are several problems:

1. you don't have `;` after insert statement
2. `IF` statement should end with `END IF` and a semicolon, not just `END`
3. you have to change a delimiter with `DELIMITER` command
4. use `EXISTS()` rather then `COUNT()`

That being said your trigger might look like

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tblspmaster_noduplicate
BEFORE INSERT ON tblspmaster
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tblspmaster WHERE sp = NEW.sp)) THEN
    INSERT INTO tblspduplicate (sp,FileImported,AMZFileName)   
    VALUES (NEW.sp, NEW.FileImported, NEW.AMZFileName);
  END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bec91/1)** demo

Use `IGNORE` clause in your `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement. MySql will treat errors (violating unique constraint) as warnings effectively discarding duplicates.

> **[LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)**
>   *If you specify IGNORE, input rows that duplicate an existing row on a unique key value are skipped.*

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'E://31october//SP//sp_files_sample1//400k sp00 6-19 E.csv' 
IGNORE  
INTO TABLE tblspmaster 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
-- IGNORE 1 LINES
```

**Note:** FYI failed inserts for duplicate rows will leave gaps in values of auto_increment `SCN` column.

---

You may consider another approach which might be more preferable performance wise:

1. create temporary staging table with no constraints and no indices
2. use `LOAD DATA INFILE` to populate staging table
3. having `tblspmaster` and the staging table and using `INSERT ... SELECT` syntax insert all duplicates in `tblspduplicate` in one go
4. insert only non-existent rows from staging table into `tblspmaster` again in one go
5. `TRUNCATE` or `DROP` staging table

Comment: Combine this with `INSERT IGNORE` to allow the duplicates to be discarded without throwing an error.

Comment: @rahularyansharma It's already in my mysql sqlfiddle example. Take a closer look. Last insert statement uses `INSERT IGNORE` syntax. In your case it should be `LOAD DATA INFILE ... IGNORE`. Otherwise the first duplicate record will throw an error.

Comment: @peterm I am using LOAD DATA local INFILE 'E://31october//SP//sp_files_sample1//400k sp00 6-19 E.csv'
INTO TABLE  tblspmaster
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(sp); for inserting records so where i can use ignore .

Comment: Right after the file name and before `INTO` clause. It's different from `IGNORE X LINES` clause.

Comment: OK i wil try this , one more thing i want to ask you that when i run first time when there is no records in master table its runs OK but when i again run this command to check trigger and values to be inserted in duplicate table . its almost stop means taking 3 hours for 400 k rows and single column value .

Comment: Can you post actual table definitions `DESC table_name` and `SHOW INDEX FROM table_name` for both tables? Now you might consider completely different approach without triggers to avoid checks on a row by row basis. I can add it to my answer a little bit latter.

Comment: @rahularyansharma See updated answer. On such amounts of rows I'd strongly recommend to consider the second approach to avoid a row by row processing. BTW did you try my version of trigger code with `LOaD INFILE IGNORE`?

Comment: @peterm thanks, I am also thinking same after working whole night on that approach.I will try this later today and will let you know if  there comes any road blocks for me . really thanks for your time .

Comment: @peterm Yes i tried that trigger code with 'Load INFILE IGNORE' but its throwing some transnational errors when i run the duplicate file .

Comment: @peterm I read your approach carefully now and i am not able to understand point 3 and 4 . why you want to fill duplicate table first instead of master table and second should i use any stored procedure for this to combine all transaction statements .

Comment: @rahularyansharma It doesn't matter at all what you'll do first p.3 or p.4 since you are not changing (deduplicating) staging table. you just select from it. You can't use `LOAD DATA INFILE` in a stored procedure. Other than that yes you can put two insert statements into a SP. Is it worth it? I'm not so sure.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36849/discussion-between-rahularyansharma-and-peterm)

Comment: @peterm How can i find effeciently duplicate records when my master table around 2 millions records and staging table have around 400k records at a time ?

Comment: @rahularyansharma To find duplicates you'll need a simple `INNER JOIN` between tables (that's one of the beauties of using a staging table). Make sure that you have an index on master table and you might consider creating an index after loading data on staging table (it actually depends how many duplicates do you usually have per file).

Comment: one more thing i want to know that is it possible insert extra column using `Load Data Local IN file`. As right now i have one column `sp` from `csv` file and want some other fields from user input .

Comment: @rahularyansharma Yes you can by properly using field list and `SET` clause of `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

Comment: @peterm As per your advice  I stay to staging table but now a problem arise in stored proecdure which is checking for duplicate records . Will you please look into this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18665972/locking-the-table-so-trnasaction-not-get-completed .

Comment: @peterm is it possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692078/update-exported-records-using-into-outfile