# FIX this code with syntax errors i am using phpMyAdmin to execute it

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

CODE :-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER user_address_check
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON street_master
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE check INT;
check = STRCMP(street_master.locality_name,NEW.name);
if(check!=1)
then dbms_output.put_line('Record Already Exists');
End IF;
END;
```

street_master name of the table , locality_name of the column

### -what i am trying to achieve

-compare each row of the column locality_name which has string(some address) stored in it with locality_name which i am about to insert ...so if there is a possible duplicate i should be notified

Should I use 'LIKE' instead of STRCMP ...if yes then how..?

Error i got after executing

## 1064 - Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de 'TRIGGER user_address_check

BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON street_master
FOR EACH R' Ã  la ligne 1

Comment: There is no `create or replace trigger ...` command in MySQL. Drop the trigger then recreate it. See [this question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/78438/is-it-possible-to-modify-an-existing-trigger-definition-in-mysql).

Comment: Then just use `create trigger`.

Comment: Read what I am trying to achieve .. first line is not what i want to fix... :|

Comment: Why do you say that? That's exactly what your error message states. Also, this seems to be a trigger that just implements a unique constraint on the table `street_master`. If this is what you're trying to do, just use a proper constraint.

Comment: If you don't like constraints then you can create trigger with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18621419/2253302